Proof of more general form of Tutte's 1-factor theorem
The actual problem reads like following:

Let $G$ be a graph and $T \subseteq V(G)$, then $G$ has a matching that saturates $T$ if and only if $o(G-S|T) \le |S|$ $\forall S \subseteq V(G)$ where $o(G-S|T)$ is the # of odd components of $G-S$ whose vectex set in contained in $T$

To solve this I had made three cases when S is completely contained in T, semi-contained in T and is disjoint from T.
When S is completely contained in T, the proof is doable along the lines of proof of Tutte 1-factor theorem. And when S is disjoint from T, then the proof is trivial (atleast for the necessary part). But for the case when T and S have a non-zero intersection, I am very confused regarding the proof.
Can somebody help me with the proof's outline?

The necessity of the condition is immediate: every odd component of $G-S$ contained in $T$ must have a vertex matched to $S$ in a $T$-saturating matching.
